# JSON data posts but table does not get populated

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json, pdo

EDIT:

1. Changed the Jquery code to recreate rows on the fly still a no go
2. Restructured my table still a no go.

I have a php script that encodes my db table into an array. I echo the json_encode and it echos just fine. script :

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="root"; // Mysql username
$password="testdbpass"; // Mysql password
$db_name="test"; // Database name

// Connect to server via PHP Data Object
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test", $username, $password);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$array = $dbh->query("SELECT id, anum, first, last,
                        why, comments, aidyear, additional_req,
                        signintime FROM inoffice WHERE 
                        counselorname IS NULL")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($array);

?>
```

I then have a page that should extract the data and then place it into a table. For some reason I can not get it TO post to my first table on that page.

these are my jquery scripts I have running on the page :

```
    <head>
    <script src="core/media/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="core/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="core/media/js/install.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
    url: 'core/media/js/getdatainoffice.php',
    type: 'GET',
    async: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (result) {

        var insert = '';

        $.each(result, function() {
            insert += '<tr><td>' + id + '</td><td>' + anum + '</td><td>' + first + '</td><td>' + last + '</td><td>' + why + 
                        '</td><td>' + comments + '</td><td>' + additional_req + '</td><td>' + aidyear + '</td><td>' 
                        + signintime + '</td></tr>';
        });
        $('#datatables tr').after(insert);
    }


});

    </script>
```

Do I need to create an array in my jquery ajax for each of the table data or from my understanding I thought json handles the way the array is encoded.

this is my table :

```
 table id='datatables' class='display'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                 <th>Session ID </th>                        
                 <th>A Number</th>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>Reason for visit</th>
                        <th>Comments</th>
                        <th>Aid Year</th>
                        <th>Additional Requirements</th>
                        <th>Signin Time</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                    <tbody>


                </tbody>
        </table>
```

Any help would or explanations would be lovely. I have been reading off this [site](http://www.jquery4u.com/json/ajaxjquery-getjson-simple/) but to no avail.

JSON array :

> [{"id":"7","anum":"B00000000","first":"rixhers","last":"ajazi","why":"Other","comments":"Jut
>   need some
>   help!!!","additional_req":"","aidyear":"12-13","signintime":"2013-01-16
>   09:08:35"},{"id":"8","anum":"A00000000","first":"rixhers","last":"ajazi","why":"Appeal","comments":"","additional_req":"","aidyear":"12-13","signintime":"2013-01-16
>   09:28:57"},{"id":"9","anum":"A00000000","first":"rixhers","last":"ajazi","why":"Appeal","comments":"","additional_req":"","aidyear":"12-13","signintime":"2013-01-16
>   10:12:07"},{"id":"10","anum":"A00000000","first":"rixhers","last":"ajazi","why":"Appeal","comments":"","additional_req":"","aidyear":"12-13","signintime":"2013-01-16
>   11:19:18"}]

More information : I am using a jquery plugin called datatables and I need to populate that table.

Answer (score 2):

```
                $.(#datatables).append(data)
```

at the point you run this, `data` is an array. You can't just append some random javascript data structure into the DOM - you'll have to actually BUILD table rows from data in that array. e.g.

```
html = ''
for (x in data) {
   html += '<tr><td>' + data['somefield'] + '</td></tr>';
}
$('#datatables').append(html);
```

If all you're doing with this data is stuff it into an html table, then it'd probably be easier to build the html on the server in PHP and shove it across the wire as a single string.

Comment: So for what you said in the later comments, your saying to build the table in the inofficejson.php where the beginning json encode is happening? - And then transmit the table with the data array?

Comment: it's up to you. but personally I hate building html in javascript and try to do as much of it as possible server-side.

Comment: alright I will get to work on that and report what I have done. Thanks a lot

Comment: I tried recreating rows with the data that I received, and still nothing. Any other tips!